# Mostrar imágenes de una carpeta en php

Tags: php, imagen

Utilizo el siguiente código para que se muestren las imágenes que tengo en una carpeta del directorio.

```html
<?php
    $dir_path = "assest/images/baul/numerosletras";
    $extensions_array = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
    
    if(is_dir($dir_path))
    {
        $files = scandir($dir_path);
        
        for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
        {
            if($files[$i] !='.' && $files[$i] !='..')
            {
                // get file name
                echo "File Name -> $files[$i]<br>";
                
                // get file extension
                $file = pathinfo($files[$i]);
                $extension = $file['extension'];
                echo "File Extension-> $extension<br>";
                
               // check file extension
                if(in_array($extension, $extensions_array))
                {
                // show image
                echo "<img src='$dir_path$files[$i]' style='width:100px;height:100px;'><br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Parece que todo funciona correctamente pero me muestra la página así:[image: Captura de la pagina web]

¿Hay alguna manera de que se muestre la imagen bien? ¿En qué me estoy equivocando?

Gracias de antemano

Un saludo

Comment: Has intentado ver el codigo de la pagina en el navegador a ver que viene en el src de las imagenes tal vez es que la url que construyes este mal o le falte algo probablemente sea un / antes del nombre del archivo pero eso debes saberlo a ciencia cierta cuando hagas lo primero ke te recomende

Comment: Jajja efectivamente es eso ahora ke revise mejor tu codigo si te fijas $dir_path es "assest/images/baul/numerosletras" y cuando concatenas lo haces de esta manera src='$dir_path$files[$i]' eso quiere decir que si tu archivo se llama por ejemplo foto1.jpg el atributo src de esa foto seria src='assest/images/baul/numerosletrasfoto1.jpg' lo cual no existe y por tanto te sale la foto vacia. Para solucionar eso solo cambia en el src='$dir_path$files[$i]' por src='$dir_path/$files[$i]'

Comment: Gracias compañero!

Comment: Voy a ponerlo como respuesta por si otro usuario tiene un problema parecido marcala como correcta si soluciono tu pregunta. ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando mejor tu codigo si te fijas `$dir_path` es `assest/images/baul/numerosletras` y cuando concatenas lo haces de esta manera

```
src='$dir_path$files[$i]'
```

Eso quiere decir que si tu archivo se llama por ejemplo `foto1.jpg` el atributo `src` de esa foto seria `src='assest/images/baul/numerosletrasfoto1.jpg'` lo cual no existe y por tanto te sale la foto vacia. Para solucionar eso solo cambia en el

```
src='$dir_path$files[$i]'
```

Por:

```
src='$dir_path/$files[$i]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Además de lo que dice @Dariel en su respuesta, podría ser también que no se está entregando tampoco bien el enlace en el `$dir_path` como podría ser el / antes de la ruta de esta manera

```
$dir_path = "/assest/images/baul/numerosletras";
```

Ya que cuando se mandan sin ese / es como sí estuviera buscando en la ruta que ya estás, a no ser que sí esté ahí, de igual manera, te lo dejo, espero que sí te sirva